# Chrome or Chromium icon doesn't show in the launcher

Tags: launcher, google-chrome, chromium

I have got Google Chrome Browser on Ubuntu 11.10, and when I open it, it won't appear on/in the sidebar. I then download Chromium, but the same thing happens. I try dragging it to the sidebar, but when I click it, it doesn't show it as open.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
apt-get remove google-chrome-stable (or whatever version you're running)
cd ~/.config
rm -rf google-chrome/
```

then logout and login, and launch chromium. It should appear in the launcher now. That's what worked for me :)