# Google Chrome icon in Unity's dash

Tags: google-chrome, icons, unity-dash

I have Google Chrome pinned, but when I click the icon another one appears which is in high detail unlike the pinned one.

If I unpin all Chrome icons, then suddenly when I pin another icon it starts the browser in a specific site that I once visited and didn't even bookmark (Deluge bittorrent client). Where are all dash icons under "Applications" located? I searched `/usr/share/applications/` but didn't find it there.

Comment: `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` is normally the `.desktop` file for google-chrome

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome opens in a new window in a new launcher icon](http://askubuntu.com/questions/396448/google-chrome-opens-in-a-new-window-in-a-new-launcher-icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the random site issue, it's going to be in your home area, under `~/.local/share/applications`.

You will probably find some strangley named ones in there - for example `chrome-gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp-Default.desktop`. I'd suggest not removing them - they're for your extensions.

However, if you see one with the name of the site that lauches, do delete it.

Comment: I deleted the whole folder /home/*USER*/.local/share/applications/ and both issues went away. Thanks, i just needed to know what other location unity dash gets its icons from

Comment: @Tim Looks to be a clear dup, I don't know probably you shouldn't answer this.

Comment: @NickBailuc You really shouldn't have deleted the whole folder but never mind...

Comment: @Ron That was only addressing the 2 icons issue, not the "non bookmarked launcher".

Comment: @Tim but the non-bookmarked launcher does go away with that answer, right? Just a suggestion, btw.