# Google Chrome does not open links from other applications

Tags: google-chrome, default-programs, default-browser

When I click on links in mails or Twitter, my default browser, which is Google Chrome, opens, but it always only displays the Google Chrome welcome page, not the link.
I found that this is set in my default applications somehow:

[image: screenshot]

You can see that the "getting started" page is set there. I don't know how this happened, how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/396448/google-chrome-opens-in-a-new-window-in-a-new-launcher-icon

Comment: @Ron thanks, this worked. I replaced google-chrome.desktop in my home folder with the one from /usr/share/applications