# Ubuntu Dock adds a new icon when I open certain programs

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I recently added Terminator (terminal emulator) to my system. When I open Terminator (whether by clicking its icon in the launcher or by hitting a keyboard shortcut), a new icon appears in my launcher (Ubuntu Dock).

[image]

What can I do to

1. have only a single icon and
2. just activate the existing Terminator window if Terminator is already running?

I don't have this problem with gnome-terminal.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

I looked at [this solution for Google Chrome's icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396448/google-chrome-opens-in-a-new-window-in-a-new-launcher-icon), but it doesn't apply: my `$HOME/.local/share/applications` doesn't include any desktop files for Terminator.

Here's the contents of my `/usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminator
Comment=Multiple terminals in one window
TryExec=terminator
Exec=terminator
Icon=terminator
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;System;
StartupNotify=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=terminator
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;
Keywords=terminal;shell;prompt;command;commandline;
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=terminator
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Update: I've found that I can avoid some of this problem by hitting the windows key, typing 'Terminator', right-clicking 'Terminator', and selecting 'Add to favourites'. ('Add to favourites' was never an option when right-clicking the Terminator icon in the launcher itself.) *However*, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open a terminal, it *still* creates a new icon in the launcher.

Comment: It's not Unity. 18.04 comes with GNOME instead of Unity by default. The screenshot, even though shows a little, suggests that it's Ubuntu Dock in GNOME (Unity Launcher has glossy backlit icons, indicator dot is also different).

Comment: Thanks, @pomsky , it appears to answer my question. I'm also grateful to Richard Quint for his succinct answer below.

Comment: have you pinned the application terminator to your favourites in the dock?

Comment: @Manik, I had indeed. I experienced this issue with and without having Terminator as a favourite in my launcher.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

Start Terminator and in the terminal run `xprop WM_CLASS`. Now place the cursor (probably it will look like a cross) over the Terminator window and click:

```
$ xprop WM_CLASS
# after clicking window
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "terminator", "Terminator"
```

Add a line to your desktop file that reads

`StartupWMClass=<second entry in WM_CLASS(STRING) without the quotes>`

This may solve your problem.